# Which objects reference my ViewController weakly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, weak-references

I used to have a retain cycle in one of my ViewControllers, but after a lot of debugging, I found the culprit and fixed it. But now, my app crashes if the VC in question has been present before but rightfully disposed of, and I switch view in my TabBarController.

I enabled NSZombie and checked the message that was sent that causes the SIGABRT.

```
-[OrderViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x151fdc00
```

In the stack trace I only find system library calls, none app specific.

1. What are possible causes that the framework will still make a call to my VC?
2. Is there a way in Xcode to see which objects have a weak reference to this specific instance of the VC?

Comment: Looks like your OrderViewController is registered as delegate for other class

Comment: You might have a valid point there. Is there a way to check which object (of which class) might have this VC as a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to debug this.

**Find culprit**

- Place Exception breakpoint
- Reproduce crash
- In the stack trace, click on the first `non __forwarding__` issue
- Look for the cuplrit, by typing in the console in Xcode: `(lldb) register read`

**General Purpose Registers**

```
ebx = 0x790257a0
edi = 0x01119988  "tabBarController: shouldSelectViewController:"
esi = 0x08a1fad1  "delegate"
ebp = 0xbfff8778
esp = 0xbfff8740
eip = 0x0099415c  UIKit`-[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 102 10 registers were unavailable.
```

`edi` = message that is sent, 
`esi` = object you send the message to, 
`eip` = why the message is sent.

This gives you information where the nil message is sent.

**Solution**

I found the issue later because of this. I nullified a delegate in `ViewDidDisappear`, but should have done so in `ViewWillDisappear`, since the pointer I was using was not valid anymore in `ViewDidDisappear`.

This code does not work. In this case, `self.tabBarController` is already nil, so I cannot use this reference to nullify the delegate.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = nil;
}
```

This code does work. I added a `NSParameterAssert` to check that the reference is valid before using it.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSParameterAssert(self.tabBarController);
    self.tabBarController.delegate = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your view controller is a delegate for any other object, set that delegate property to nil inside the view controller's dealloc.